# productSearchHit is returned with empty allPromotionIDs

Tags: commerce-cloud

I want to leverage the data from the productSearchHit model:

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC4/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_catalog_ProductSearchHit.html

In particular I am interested in the allPromotionIDs property.

I have created a promotion with qualifying product. When I hit my product listing page (which is a Search-Show) my debugger shows allPromotionIDs for the given product to be empty, and empty:false.

Am I mis-understanding how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the option in Search Preferences to index promotions?

This is documented here: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/search_and_navigation/b2c_setting_search_preferences.html?resultof=%22%53%65%61%72%63%68%22%20%22%73%65%61%72%63%68%22%20%22%70%72%65%66%65%72%65%6e%63%65%73%22%20%22%70%72%65%66%65%72%22%20